# sencha list background image with layout fit

Tags: image, list, background, extjs

i want to add a background to a list that is in a tab panel. but as soon as i make the layout fit, the background disappears...if i remove layout, the list disappears..

the list only seems to appear when the layout is fit...

can any one help out?

plz thanks...

```
    ****************************  Bollist.js  **********************

    Ext.define('tabla.view.Bollist',
{
    extend:'Ext.Panel',
    xtype:'Bollist',
    config:{
        title:'Bols',
        iconCls:'music2',
        layout:'fit',
        items:[
            {
                xtype:'list',
                store:'BolStore',
                itemTpl:'{name}'
            }
        ]
    }
});

     *************** Main.js **************

    Ext.define("tabla.view.Main", {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
requires: [
    'Ext.TitleBar',
    'Ext.dataview.List'
],
config: {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    items: [
        {
            style:{
                backgroundImage:'url(resources/images/bg.png)',
                backgroundRepeat:'repeat',
                backgroundPosition:'center',
                backgroundSize:'cover'
            },
            xtype:'home'
        },
        {
            style:{
                background:'red',
                backgroundRepeat:'repeat',
                backgroundPosition:'center',
                backgroundSize:'cover'
            },
            xtype:'Bollist'
        }
    ]
}
```

});

```
    Ext.define('tabla.store.BolStore',{
extend:'Ext.data.Store',
config:
{
    model:'tabla.model.Bol',
    data:[
        { name: 'Na/Ta' },
        { name: 'Ti' },
        { name: 'Tin' },
        { name: 'Ri'},
        { name: 'Ge' },
        { name: 'Ka/Kat'},
        { name: 'Dha'},
        { name: 'Dhi'},
        { name: 'Dhin'},
        { name: 'Toon'}
    ]
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach this is working for me.

Remove **style** from your list :

```
      style:{
             background:'red',
            backgroundRepeat:'repeat',
            backgroundPosition:'center',
            backgroundSize:'cover'
        }
```

Add  **CSS file** in your **index.html** like this :

```
  <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

In your **app.css** add the following code :

```
 .x-list
{
  background:'red';
}
```

Hope this helps.